# Get the value of select tag jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a code like

```
<select id="sel1">
    <option label="l1" value="1">Cool</option>
    <option label="l2" value="2">Hot</option>
</select>
```

Now I want to get the value should be either Cool or Hot while changing the value of selected item in jQuery.
I am trying by `querySource = $("#querySource").val();` but this is showing as `1` or `2`.

How to do that?

Comment: `alert($("#sel1 option:selected").text());`

Comment: Please use this code for getting the value $('#sel1 option:selected').text();

Answer (score 8):

Please use this one :

If you want to get text value  :  like Cool and Hot then ues this one

```
$('#sel1 option:selected').text();
```

If you want to get value : like 1,2 then

```
$('#sel1 option:selected').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

Through `.val()` you will receive the value of the value attribute. You can fetch the text through `.text()`.

Use this method on your selected option! See [this answer!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17692528/2580794)

Comment: but if I do it by using .text() then it is showing the whole <select><option..>...</option></select> which should not be expected

Answer (score 1):

Use `option:selected`

```
querySource = $("#querySource option:selected").text();
```

Also you may use the followings

```
$("#querySource option").is("selected").text()
$("#querySource").children("option").is("selected").text()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#sel1 option:selected").text()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
$("#querySource option:selected").text();
```